# Service access another service on 127.0.0.1?

Tags: docker, docker-compose

I'd like my web Docker container to access Redis on 127.0.0.1:6379 from within the web container. I've setup my Docker Compose file as the following. I get `ECONNREFUSED` though:

```
version: "3"

services:
  web:
    build: .
    ports:
      - 8080:8080
    command: ["test"]
    links:
      - redis:127.0.0.1
  redis:
    image: redis:alpine
    ports: 
      - 6379
```

Any ideas?

Comment: What's the `docker-compose` command you are using to bring the services up?

Comment: Why do you need to access it as `127.0.0.1:6379` rather than calling it as `redis:6379`?

Comment: @BMitch The web script can a) use a localhost instance of Redis while developing (manually installed on my laptop for instance) and should b) be able to run in a docker Compose context. In the web application, 127.0.0.1 is used.

Comment: The location of the redis database should be a configuration parameter you can pass in rather than hardcoded in your app. Then you just pass in the different configuration with a config file, environment variable, or CLI argument.

Comment: You can also use docker containers in development on the desktop. No need to develop in one environment and run it in a different environment.

Comment: @BMitch We have a complicated production environment which also doesn't utilize Dockers (which is very unfortunate). So we must be able to enable 127.0.01 for this service :/ I wish I could use Docker as you are stating.

Comment: @BMitch I completely agree with you on the configuration part. This module I'm working on however is in a separate repository which doesn't have access to the said configuration. I am including, however, a command line configuration argument just for this purpose. But until then..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The short answer to this is "don't". Docker containers each get their own loopback interface, 127.0.0.1, that is separate from the host loopback and from that of other containers. You can't redefine 127.0.0.1, and if you could, that would almost certainly break other things.

---

There is a technically possible way to do it by either running all containers directly on the host, with:

```
network_mode: "host"
```

However, that removes the docker network isolation that you'll want with containers.

You can also attach one container to the network of another container (so they have the same loopback interface) with:

```
docker run --net container:$container_id ...
```

but I'm not sure if there's a syntax to do this in `docker-compose` and it's not available in swarm mode since containers may run on different nodes. The main use I've had for this syntax is attach network debugging tools like [nicolaka/netshoot](https://github.com/nicolaka/netshoot).

---

What you should do instead is make the location of the redis database a configuration parameter to your webapp container. Pass the location in as an environment variable, config file, or command line parameter. If the web app can't support this directly, update the configuration with an entrypoint script that runs before you start your web app. This would change your compose yml file to look like:

```
version: "3"

services:
  web:
    # you should include an image name
    image: your_webapp_image_name
    build: .
    ports:
      - 8080:8080
    command: ["test"]
    environment:
      - REDIS_URL=redis:6379

    # no need to link, it's deprecated, use dns and the network docker creates
    #links:
    #  - redis:127.0.0.1
  redis:
    image: redis:alpine
    # no need to publish the port if you don't need external access
    #ports: 
    #  - 6379
```